# I gained this error in my gradle and i don't seem to understand what's happening. My gradle file is printed below

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Blockquote

I don't seem to understand the problem any help?

Kees

Comment: look this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29956850/gradle-build-errorandroid-java-exe-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-1

Answer (score 1):

Clean your project and rebuild again. this works for me like charm